# IdentityServer4 losing original returnUrl when using External Login server

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect

Unfortunately, given the size of the project, I can’t easily share a reproducible version.  However, hopefully what I have below will shed some light on my issue and you’ll see where I made a mistake.

I have two sites, an ASP.Net Core MVC application and a Login server, also ASP.Net Core MVC.  Let’s call them http://mvc.mysite.com and http://login.mysite.com.  Neither are significantly different from the IdentityServer4 Quickstart #6.  The only real difference is that I have implemented an external login provider for AzureAd.  My code for that is below.

**Scenario 1**

Given an internal login flow, where the user uses an internal login page at http://login.mysite.com everything works fine.

1. User visits http://mvc.mysite.com/clients/client-page-1
2. User is redirected to http://login.mysite.com/Account/Login
3. User logs in with correct username/password
4. User is redirected to http://mvc.mysite.com/clients/client-page-1

**Scenario 2**

However, if the login server’s AccountController::Login() method determines there is a single ExternalLoginProvider and executes the line “return await ExternalLogin(vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl);” then the original redirectUrl is lost.

1. User visits http://mvc.mysite.com/clients/client-page-1
2. User is redirected to http://login.mysite.com/Account/Login (receiving the output of AccountController::ExternalLogin)
3. User is redirected to AzureAd External OIDC Provider
4. User logs in with correct username/password
5. User is redirected to http://login.mysite.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback
6. User is redirected to http://mvc.mysite.com (Notice that the user is redirected to the root of the MVC site instead of /clients/client-page-1)

**For Scenario 1:**

- Given the MVC site
- When using the debugger to inspect the Context provided to the OpenIdConnectEvents (e.g. OnMessageReceived, OnUserInformationReceived, etc.)
- Then all Contexts have a Properties object that contains a RedirectUri == “http://mvc.mysite.com/clients/client-page-1”

**For Scenario 2:**

- Given the MVC site
- When using the debugger to inspect the Context provided to the OpenIdConnectEvents (e.g. OnMessageReceived, OnUserInformationReceived, etc.)
- Then all Contexts have a Properties object that contains a RedirectUri == “http://mvc.mysite.com” (missing the /client.client-page-1)

In my login server’s Startup.cs I have added this to ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
      .AddAzureAd(options =>
      {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            AzureAdOptions.Settings = options;
      });
```

The implementation of AddAzureAd is as follows: (You’ll see options objects handed around, I have replaced all uses of options with constant values except for ClientId and ClientSecret).

```
public static class AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        builder.AddOpenIdConnect("AzureAd", "Azure AD", options =>
        {
            var opts = new AzureAdOptions();
            configureOptions(opts);
            var config = new ConfigureAzureOptions(opts);
            config.Configure(options);
        });
        return builder;
    }

    private class ConfigureAzureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
    {
        private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;

        public ConfigureAzureOptions(AzureAdOptions azureOptions)
        {
            _azureOptions = azureOptions;
        }

        public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions) : this(azureOptions.Value) {}

        public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            Configure(options);
        }

        public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"; //_azureOptions.Authority;
            options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc"; // _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // true in production // _azureOptions.RequireHttps;
            options.ClientSecret = _azureOptions.ClientSecret;

            // Add code for hybridflow
            options.ResponseType = "id_token code";

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps), 
                // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                ValidateIssuer = false,
            };

            // Subscribing to the OIDC events
            options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
            options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Redeems the authorization code by calling AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync in order to ensure
        /// that the cache has a token for the signed-in user.
        /// </summary>
        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
        {
            string userObjectId = (context.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(context.Options.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectId, context.HttpContext.Session));
            var credential = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientId, context.Options.ClientSecret);

            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.TokenEndpointRequest.Code,
                new Uri(context.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), credential, context.Options.Resource);

            // Notify the OIDC middleware that we already took care of code redemption.
            context.HandleCodeRedemption(authResult.AccessToken, context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken);
        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
        {
            throw context.Exception;
        }
    }
}

public class NaiveSessionCache : TokenCache
{
    private static readonly object FileLock = new object();
    string UserObjectId = string.Empty;
    string CacheId = string.Empty;
    ISession Session = null;

    public NaiveSessionCache(string userId, ISession session)
    {
        UserObjectId = userId;
        CacheId = UserObjectId + "_TokenCache";
        Session = session;
        this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
        Load();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        lock (FileLock)
            this.Deserialize(Session.Get(CacheId));
    }

    public void Persist()
    {
        lock (FileLock)
        {
            // reflect changes in the persistent store
            Session.Set(CacheId, this.Serialize());
            // once the write operation took place, restore the HasStateChanged bit to false
            this.HasStateChanged = false;
        }
    }

    // Empties the persistent store.
    public override void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        Session.Remove(CacheId);
    }

    public override void DeleteItem(TokenCacheItem item)
    {
        base.DeleteItem(item);
        Persist();
    }

    // Triggered right before ADAL needs to access the cache.
    // Reload the cache from the persistent store in case it changed since the last access.
    void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        Load();
    }

    // Triggered right after ADAL accessed the cache.
    void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
        if (this.HasStateChanged)
            Persist();
    }
}
```

Comment: What values do you have in the client(s) for the redirect uri's and what are the values when registering those clients in the IDS itself?

Comment: What is your `Asp.Net Core` version and `IdentityServer4` version? I made a test with asp.net core 2.1 and IdentityServer4 with Microsoft authentication, it works correctly. To check whether it is specific to `AAD`, I suggest you make a test with Microsoft authentication in your project, and make a test with `AAD` in my test project [IdentityServerWithAspNetCoreIdentity](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/master/IdentityServerWithAspNetCoreIdentity)

Comment: Is this issue solved already?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was something we were doing incorrectly.